# Read data in main from other model in opl

Tags: cplex, opl

I have an OPL project in Cplex and I want to read one integer variable in main.mod from x.mod. I defined the variable like:
    `{int} hub = { s | s in facilities : y[s] == 1 };` (This definition is in x.mod)
How can I use hub, in main.mod, because when I write hub it's said: unknown variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use opl.hub where opl is the OPL submodel.

Let me give you a tiny example:

sub.mod

```
{int} facilities={1,2};

dvar boolean y[facilities];

subject to
{
y[1]==1;
y[2]==0;
}

{int} hub = { s | s in facilities : y[s] == 1 };
```

and then if you write main.mod

```
main {
  var source = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");
  var cplex = new IloCplex();
  var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);



  var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
opl.generate();
  if (cplex.solve()) {
     writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());
     opl.postProcess();
     writeln("hub = ",opl.hub);
  } else {
     writeln("No solution");
  }

 opl.end();


}
```

You'll get

```
OBJ = 0
hub =  {1}
```